# Why won't my plot show abline?

Tags: r

I know that there are loads of questions about this, but I can't find an answer.
I have a simple regression lm model but it wont plot the darn abline!

> thulemcmodel=lm(thulemca~thulecosmicray, data=mc)
>
> plot(mc$thulemca, mc$thulecosmicray, ylim=c(3000,5000))
>
> abline(thulemcmodel)

What's gone wrong?

Comment: in your case: `plot(thulemca ~ thulecosmicray, data=mc, ylim=c(3000,5000))`

Comment: It doesnt work. When I use that the graph doesnt even plot!

Comment: Try taking out the `ylim` values.  It's not clear which variable you intend to have have as the x (independent) and which you intend to have as the y (dependent) variable, but the `lm()` and `plot()` specifications must agree, and your x- and y-axis limits must be sensible.